# h5py: slicing dataset without loading into memory

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

Is it possible to slice an h5py dataset in two subsets without actually loading them into memory? E.g.:

```
dset = h5py.File("/2tbhd/tst.h5py","r")

X_train = dset['X'][:N/2]
X_test  = dset['X'][N/2:-1]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: The code he posted will instantly load those data points into memory.  He wants to pass around two references to the two halves of his data, without passing around big arrays.

Comment: I know of no way to do this.  At first I thought region references might somehow be what you need, but as far as I can tell, that's not the answer.

Comment: Now I remember this old thread on the h5py mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/h5py/9WKEiIIBBR8/lbaXCZ7WQFYJ

Comment: @JohnZwinck, as superbatfish said, this code instantly load data into memory.

Answer (score 4):

No.

You would need to implement your own class to act as a view on the dataset.  [An old thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/h5py/9WKEiIIBBR8/lbaXCZ7WQFYJ) on the h5py mailing list indicates that such a `DatasetView` class is theoretically possible to implement using HDF5 dataspaces, but probably not worth it for many use cases.  Element-wise access would be very slow compared to a normal numpy array (assuming you can fit your data into memory).

**Edit:** If you want to avoid messing with HDF5 data spaces (whatever that means), you might settle for a simpler approach.  Try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stuarteberg/7ecd8cb7b24d12f4ffd9) I just wrote.  Use it like this:

```
dset = h5py.File("/2tbhd/tst.h5py","r")

from simpleview import SimpleView
X_view = SimpleView(dset['X'])

# Stores slices, but doesn't load into memory
X_train = X_view[:N/2]
X_test  = X_view[N/2:-1]

# These statements will load the data into memory.
print numpy.sum(X_train)
print numpy.array(X_test)[0]
```

Note that the slicing support in this simple example is somewhat limited.  If you want full slicing and element-wise access, you'll have to copy it into a real array:

```
X_train_copy = numpy.array(X_train)
```